# Graceful File Reading without Locking

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, synchronization, locking

### Whiteboard Overview

The images below are `1000 x 750 px, ~130 kB JPEGs` hosted on ImageShack.

- [Internal](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/3152/internalr.jpg)
- [Global](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/8249/globalw.jpg)

---

### Additional Information

I should mention that each user (of the client boxes) will be working straight off the `/Foo` share. Due to the nature of the business, users will never need to see or work on each other's documents concurrently, so conflicts of this nature will never be a problem. Access needs to be as simple as possible for them, which probably means mapping a drive to their respective `/Foo/username` sub-directory.

Additionally, no one but my applications (in-house and the ones on the server) will be using the FTP directory directly.

---

### Possible Implementations

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like I can use off the shelf tools such as WinSCP because some other logic needs to be intimately tied into the process.

I figure there are two simple ways for me to accomplishing the above on the in-house side.

1. Method one (slow):

   - Walk the `/Foo` directory tree every N minutes.
   - Diff with previous tree using a combination of timestamps (can be faked by file copying tools, but not relevant in this case) and check-summation.
   - Merge changes with off-site FTP server.
2. Method two:

   - Register for directory change notifications (e.g., using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` from the WinAPI, or `FileSystemWatcher` if using .NET).
   - Log changes.
   - Merge changes with off-site FTP server every N minutes.

I'll probably end up using something like the second method due to performance considerations.

---

### Problem

Since this synchronization must take place during business hours, the first problem that arises is during the off-site upload stage.

While I'm transferring a file off-site, I effectively need to prevent the users from writing to the file (e.g., use `CreateFile` with `FILE_SHARE_READ` or something) while I'm reading from it. The internet upstream speeds at their office are nowhere near symmetrical to the file sizes they'll be working with, so it's quite possible that they'll come back to the file and attempt to modify it while I'm still reading from it.

---

### Possible Solution

The easiest solution to the above problem would be to create a copy of the file(s) in question elsewhere on the file-system and transfer those "snapshots" without disturbance.

The files (some will be binary) that these guys will be working with are relatively small, probably ≤20 MB, so copying (and therefore temporarily locking) them will be almost instant. The chances of them attempting to write to the file in the same instant that I'm copying it should be close to nil.

This solution seems kind of ugly, though, and I'm pretty sure there's a better way to handle this type of problem.

One thing that comes to mind is something like a file system filter that takes care of the replication and synchronization at the IRP level, kind of like what some A/Vs do. This is overkill for my project, however.

---

### Questions

This is the first time that I've had to deal with this type of problem, so perhaps I'm thinking too much into it.

I'm interested in clean solutions that don't require going overboard with the complexity of their implementations. Perhaps I've missed something in the WinAPI that handles this problem gracefully?

I haven't decided what I'll be writing this in, but I'm comfortable with: C, C++, C#, D, and Perl.

Comment: +1 for the perfectly written question.

Comment: What's the time-range required for the snapshot to be synced on the external server, also can you give us a reason for the ftp, are there backup's being made ? why specifically during business hours ?

Comment: I think writing this yourself is (more or less) a mistake. You'd be better off configuring a Windows distributed file system (DFS) and just using the data from there. Windows also has File Replication Service (FRS), but DFS is (at least supposedly) better tuned for use over a WAN.

Comment: @RobertPitt: As soon as possible after the N minutes are up, while utilizing no more than 40% of their upstream bandwidth.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Thanks, I didn't know about those. I'll take a look and see if they fulfill my needs.

Comment: Replication as Jerry says is the best method but there are several factors that may be an issue, i.e The utilization of bandwidth, the hops required for the transfer, is the server for the ftp part of the domain etc

Comment: It's not a real answer, but maybe you should prototype using the simplest option: ReadDirectoryChanges with a temporary copy, it's not ideal, but maybe it's good enough.

Comment: @RobertPitt: FTP because it's the only reasonable way I can transfer files to the server (which belongs to another client). During business hours because that's when these files change and my boss and his client want the remote server to have very recent copies of the files in question. This is not used for backups at all, but more like a defective file sharing mechanism. That's what happens when business people start making technical decisions. :(

Comment: Aren't there products out there that do this?

Comment: If the files are used so that members of the staff can work from alternative locations, have you looked into a VPN System such Cisco?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Probably, but I'll need intimate knowledge of what operations have been performed because other systems rely on me to call on them via an RPC mechanism. So I'll need a product that allows me to register for change events. I don't think parsing log files (even if they're something like XML) is acceptable. So at this point it's cleaner for me to write something myself because the problem at hand seems pretty trivial.

Comment: @RobertPitt: These files need to be consumed by our client only. Now, our client has their own clients and they are the ones who will ultimately be downloading these files from a private website hosted elsewhere. Think of our company as a sub-contractor in this instance. Anyway, I just started here a few weeks ago and it's my first job out of University so I'm still confused about everything. I'd rather not tell my boss "go buy something else" on my first project, however dumb it may be. :)

Comment: @fulcrum, I understand your trivial pursuit, I'me just trying to look at the whole operation and see if there are better mean's of completing the project, you should certainly look into DFS, but if its collaboration that the end-user would require then you could use Sharepoint Foundation on-site and allow the files to be managed on a web platform, also abiding by your Active Directory records, Permissions etc

Comment: @RoberPitt: Yeah, but it's a weird collaboration. We're supposed to provide data for our client's clients without them knowing that it was us that is doing the actual work. Atleast that's what my boss told me. Also, I just looked at a long e-mail exchange regarding this project. Seems like the remote servers are all running *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussions in the comments my proposal would be like so:

- Create a partition on your data server, about 5GB for safety.
- Create a Windows Service Project in C# that would monitor your data driver / location.
- When a file has been modified then create a local copy of the file, containing the same directory structure and place on the new partition.
- Create another service that would do the following:

  - Monitor Bandwidth Usages
  - Monitor file creations on the temporary partition.
  - Transfer several files at a time (Use Threading) to your FTP Server, abiding by the bandwidth usages at the current time, decreasing / increasing the worker threads depending on network traffic.
  - Remove the files from the partition that have successfully transferred.

So basically you have your drives:

- `C:` Windows Installation
- `D:` Share Storage
- `X:` Temporary Partition

Then you would have following services:

- `LocalMirrorService` - Watches `D:` and copies to `X:` with the dir structure
- `TransferClientService` - Moves files from `X:` to ftp server, removes from `X:`

  - Also use multi threads to move multiples and monitors bandwidth.

I would bet that this is the idea that you had in mind but this seems like a reasonable approach as long as your really good with your application development and your able create a solid system that would handle most issues.

When a user edits a document in Microsoft Word for instance, the file will change on the share and it may be copied to `X:` even though the user is still working on it, within windows there would be an API see if the file handle is still opened by the user, if this is the case then you can just create a hook to watch when the user actually closes the document so that all there edits are complete, then you can migrate to drive `X:`.

this being said that if the user is working on the document and there PC crashes for some reason, the document / files handle may not get released until the document is opened at a later date, thus causing issues.

Comment: +1, It's exactly what I proposed, "simple" and probably good enough.

Comment: Yeah, it's what I planned to do anyway. I ran some tests and it seems very unlikely that this setup will cause problems for the in-house users. Thanks for writing a detailed answer, also. :)

Comment: Also look into doing some kind of queue system for the transfer to `X:` as if the user saves a doc 2x in 1min yea can just update the queue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in a similar situation (I'm assuming the person who asked the question implemented a solution long ago), I would suggest an implementation of [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

rsync.net's [Windows Backup Agent](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_backup_agent.html) does what is described in method 1, and can be run as a service as well (see "[Advanced Usage](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_advanced_agent.html)"). Though I'm not entirely sure if it has built-in bandwidth limiting...

Another (probably better) solution that *does* have bandwidth limiting is [Duplicati](http://www.duplicati.com/). It also properly backs up currently-open or locked files. Uses SharpRSync, a managed rsync implementation, for its backend. Open source too, which is always a plus!